# Cutting over to a different storage class

Tags: kubernetes, storage, volume

I currently have a default storage `class (A)` with a reclaimPolicy of "Retain," but I want to switch this to `Delete`. I've created a second storage `class (B)` with a reclaimPolicy of `Retain`. If I have a service that `switches` to use `B` instead of `A`, does that mean they get a whole new volume? Is it possible to reuse the same volume?

Looking for help with a good cutover plan. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: But nothing will change if you switch from Service A to B, ot I`m misunderstand you? Because the reclaim policy the same `Retain`

Comment: @NickRak but i am moving A to "Delete" eventually. Is there any chance that the volume gets reprovisioned?